# USB device read fails when Microsoft Edge is open

Tags: usb, microsoft-edge

I have a Win32 MFC application which connects to a USB device via a Bulk interface. It's been working OK for years.

But now, on Windows 10, when Microsoft Edge (96.0.1054.43) is open the USB read operation times out.

Maybe the USB data written to the device hasn't arrived but the WriteFile call is returning the correct number of bytes.  But that's probably the write to the driver rather than the device.

If I change the timeout to 10 seconds it still times out.  It seems that Microsoft Edge might be completely blocking the USB connection to the device.

The driver is Microsoft's user mode USB driver (WdfCoInstaller01009.dll) and is fully signed.

Has anyone else observed this behaviour and is there a fix?

This is not just an issue with my PC but with customers elsewhere.  Everything works perfectly except when Microsoft Edge is open.  It happens also when Chrome is open.

**Update**

Disabling 2 options in Microsoft Edge fixes this issue:

- Startup Boost
- Continue running background extensions and apps when Microsoft Edge is closed

Both of these options must be disabled.

Chrome has a setting:

- Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed

but disabling this does not fix the issue.

Comment: What's the **Windows version and edition**? Please, add those infos to your post.

Comment: Did you already check out the **USB device and system one health**? Verify that with **[CrystalDiskInfo software](https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/)**.

Comment: In Edge settings, check if "Ask when a site wants to access USB devices" is turned on.

Comment: @harrymc It makes no difference if "Ask when a site wants to access USB devices" is turned on or off.

Comment: Does it happen when both Edge and Chrome are opened?

Comment: @harrymc Yes if I open both Edge and Chrome it still happens.

Comment: Your application or third party?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat My application

Comment: What does your application do with the USB? Which API does it use to open it, and how long does it keep it open?